# I want to find populate OR search, mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**My model code:**

```
var user = mongoose.Schema({
email: ....
password: .....
name : ...
company : ...
position : ....
phoneNumber : ...
signDate : Date,
friends: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ,unique: true, ref: 'user' }],
accessToken: .....
});
```

**And:**

```
var friend = mongoose.Schema({
    friends: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ,unique: true, ref: 'user' }]
});
```

**Using these two, I want to search for all the fields using a single keyword.**

```
var fds = new Friend;

User.findOne({email : user.email})
.populate({ 
      path  : 'friends',
      match     : ''''empty''''
})
.exec(function (err, fd) {
      if(!err){
        fds = fd.friends;
        res.render('account/friend', { layout: false, user: user, friends: fds });
      }else{ console.log(err)}
});
```

**I don't know what to put in that empty space.**

```
var term = new RegExp(req.body.inputAll, 'i');

User.find().or([{ email: { $regex: term }}, 
                { name: { $regex: term }}, 
                { company: { $regex: term }}, 
                { position: { $regex: term }}, 
                { phoneNumber: { $regex: term }}])
```

Elsewhere this was the word OR search. But I don't know how to populate OR search, or other way besides to using the Match?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `$or` operator to OR the queries for `match`. Something like this :

```
User.findOne({email : user.email})
  .populate({ 
    path  : 'friends',
    match : {
        $or: [
                { email: { $regex: term }},
                { name: { $regex: term }},
                { company: { $regex: term }},
                { position: { $regex: term }}, 
                { phoneNumber: { $regex: term }}
            ]
    }
})
.exec(function (err, fd) {
    if(!err){
        fds = fd.friends;
        res.render('account/friend', { layout: false, user: user, friends: fds });
    }
    else{ 
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

Comment: OMG really thank you. So I resolved

populate({ 
    path : 'friends',
    match : { $or: [{ email: { $regex: term }}, 
                    { name: { $regex: term }}, 
                    { company: { $regex: term }}, 
                    { position: { $regex: term }}, 
                    { phoneNumber: { $regex: term }}]
                }
 })