# Mongoose match different fields when populated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model(User), which has two ref objects(Training, Evaluation), each ref object holds some content with results on different dates.

When I populate, I want to filter data of "Training" & "Evaluation" results at specific dates.

I am trying something like this, please help

```
Mnguser.find({})
    .populate({
        path: 'Training Evaluation',
        match: {
            'Training.trainDate':{
                $gt: firstDay,
                $lt: lastDay
            },
            'Evaluation.evalDate':{
                $gt: firstDay,
                $lt: lastDay
             }
        }
    })
    .then(res){results}
```

Note: Training & Evaluation are an array of objects, above is just a view of my thought.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read this question-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303294/querying-after-populate-in-mongoose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying after populate in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303294/querying-after-populate-in-mongoose)

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, but here i have an array of objects, i want to filter date in each of the ref array objects.

Comment: Here i am dealing with two different population and different field names of each populated array objects

Comment: can you share yours schema's  ?

Comment: could you solve it?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400361/i-want-to-find-populate-or-search-mongoose