# How to retrieve data with Foreign key like constraint in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to interact with MongoDB.
I have created two schemas. One schema has reference of another schema -

```
const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});

const ArticleSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    dateOfCreation: {type: Date, required: true},
    dateOfModification: {type: Date, required: true},
    content: {type: String, required: true},
    author: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
});
```

There are two collections in my DB, `User` and `Articles`. The`ArticleSchema` has reference of the `UserSchema`.
I want search the `Articles` written by a particular author's username. I have read about the `populate` method of mongoose but I don't know how to use the method for combined search.
How can I search for the articles with by an author's username?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to find populate OR search, mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400361/i-want-to-find-populate-or-search-mongoose)

Comment: @turivishal I followed that solution to that question. It does not work for me.